# Android Query CallLog given a date

Tags: android, calllog

I want to query CallLog database and return some calls based on a specified date. For instance, I want to be able to get data from a given date i.e September 1st until now.

I query the database by calling:

```
        Date d = new Date();


    String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " > " + d.toString();
    /* Query the CallLog Content Provider */
 /*Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
           null, null, strOrder);*/
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        Log.d(TAG, "Did not have permissions.");
        return;
    }
    Cursor managedCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, strOrder);
```

This gives me an error and does not launchs the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specified the error you are receiving i can only give you an example that does work in my code:

```
String query = "( " + CallLog.Calls.DATE + " >= " + from +
            " AND " + CallLog.Calls.DATE + " <= " + to + ")";

Cursor callsCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                                CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, 
                                null, 
                                query, 
                                null, 
                                null, 
                                CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");


if (callsCursor != null) {
    while (callsCursor.moveToNext()) {
         String number = callsCursor.getString(callsCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
         int type = callsCursor.getInt(callsCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
         long date = callsCursor.getLong(callsCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
         int duration = callsCursor.getInt(callsCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));

         // the rest of your code goes here
    }
}
```

hope it helps